# How to create dataframe using results (output) of crosstabulation and same dataframe export into Excel?

Tags: r

```
data_cards=crosstab(cards_data, row.vars="flag1", col.vars="flag2", type="f")

flag2        <=33%   0%  100% 34-67% 68-99%  Sum
flag1                                           
1-2                0   3   6     6      0  104
10+                5   9  33     2     39   88
3-5                7  13  12     4     24   60
6-10               5   6   5     2     21   39
Sum               17  31  56    14     84  291
```

but when I export this result into excel I am getting transposing output of `flag 1` and `flag 2`.

Can any one suggest me as it is output export into Excel?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the result of `dput(data_cards)` or `dput(cards_data)` to your post. How did you export it?

Comment: Sorry the output result only i mention in the post

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get answers, please read [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., provide (artificial) input data & what lines of code you tried.